# agda-compute-normalised-maybe-toplevel shows the correct type, yet `refl` isn't accepted

Tags: agda

I'm trying to write a pretty print for a basic language syntax, with the property that the output of the pretty printer should correctly parse as the thing it's printing. I have the following:

```
data Syntax : Set where
  string : List Char -> Syntax

parse : List Char → Maybe Syntax
parse ('"' ∷ '"' ∷ _) = just (string [])
parse _ = nothing
```

The parser can only parse the string `""` as an empty literal string for now, but it's a start :)

Next, I have my pretty printer:

```
pretty-lit : (s : Syntax) → pretty-printer-for (string l)
pretty-lit (string []) = char '"' <> char '"', {!!}
pretty-lit (string (x ∷ xs)) = {!!}
```

The pretty-printer-for type is:

```
pretty-printer-for : (s : Syntax) → Set
pretty-printer-for s = Σ Doc (λ d → parse (display (render-pretty 80 d)) ≡ just s)
```

That is, a dependent product of a `Doc` (ala Wadler's pretty printing) and a proof that parsing the result of rendering that `Doc` to a string is indeed the syntax you started with.

Now, the first hole in `pretty-lit` above has this goal:

```
Goal: parse
      (display (render-pretty 80 (cat (char '\"') (char '\"'))))
      ≡ just (string [])
————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
```

If I completely comment out `pretty-lit` and use `agda-compute-normalised-maybe-toplevel`, then `parse (display (render-pretty 80 (cat (char '\"') (char '\"'))))` computes to `just (string [])`, which is what I'd expect. However, if I try and use `refl` as the contents of that hole, I get

```
parse
(display (render-pretty (fromNat 80) (char '\"' <> char '\"')))
!= just (string []) of type Maybe Syntax
when checking that the expression refl has type
parse
(display (render-pretty (fromNat 80) (char '\"' <> char '\"')))
≡ just (string [])
```

But I just checked and they are equal! Oddly, `pretty-lit` with holes (as above) is in scope, the `agda-computer-normalised-maybe-toplevel` *doesn't* compute `just (string [])`, but I have no idea why.

Full source can be found at https://github.com/ocharles/agda-nixfmt/commit/4df637cce0621b3d9d8a3ee0a104f46523dcc908, including the definition of my pretty printer.

Answer (score 4):

`{AS}` on #agda woke up just a I posted this and found the problem - I had `render-pretty` marked as `NON_TERMINATING`. Agda can't see that this function is terminating, but I know it is - I just didn't realise there was a `TERMINATING` pragma :) With that, everything is good.

Comment: I see you're implementing Wadler's best, you may be interested in [techniques to make termination obvious](http://gallais.github.io/blog/termination-tricks.html). This way you can avoid pragmas altogether.